# Highlighting in solr with python

Tags: python, django, solr, highlight

If I want to achieve highlight function of **Solr** in **Django** with **python**, how could it be done by using the package *solrpy*?

How did *solrpy* deal with it, as the highlighting results live in a absolute fragment on the **SolrResponse** object,shown as a dictionary of dictionaries.

What's more, does *solrpy* still work for more function of **solr** such as faceting, highlighting and stuff, besides basic query

```
sc = solr.SolrConnection("http://localhost:8080/solr/cases")
response_c=sc.query('name:*%s'%q+'*',fields='name,decision_date', highlight='name')

print(response_c.results)
for hit in response_c.results:
  print(hit)
```

And why above code does not work to achieve Highlighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting information is stored in a separate entry named `highlighting` on the response object:

```
If you pass in `highlight` to the SolrConnection.query call,
then the response object will also have a "highlighting" property,
which will be a dictionary.
```

That being said, I strongly recommend using pysolr instead of solrpy, as pysolr is maintained by the django-haystack project and has been developed continuously over the last few years compared to solrpy.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness and I've achieved it! For a step further, I want to know how to substitute highlighting content for the corresponding content in order to show the <em> tag in web page of Django. Should I create a new model and put it into page or do something else?  Would you please teach me some method to achieve it or show me the code as I've not very familiar with Django. Thanks again

Comment: I haven't written django in many years, but I assume you'd send the result to your template and make sure to allow HTML for the content included. Be careful that other HTML content in your fields are properly escaped. Try to solve it first and ask a new question if you don't get there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The code below allows highlighting (pysolr, version 3.6.0):

```
import pysolr

solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/<core/collection>')  
results = solr.search('hello', **{
        'hl': 'true',
        'hl.fragsize': 10,
        'hl.field': 'text'
    })

for i in results:
   print(i)
print(results.highlighting)
```

`results.highlighting` field will store the highlighted snippets of the search. Other fields are `facets`, `grouped`, `hits`, `spellcheck`, `stats`. See more info at https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr